# Assign namespace and dimension for Azure Application Insights for a custom metric from Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-application-insights

I am submitting custom metrics from my Java application to Azure Application Insights.  Every few seconds a thread wakes up, gets the metrics from the application, and pushes them to Azure.  Here is some sample code for how I am doing this:

```
TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
MetricTelemetry telemetry = new MetricTelemetry();
telemetry.setTimestamp(metricbean.getMetricTimestamp());
telemetry.setName("My custom metric");
telemetry.setValue( metricbean.getValue());
telemetry.setCount(1);
telemetryClient.trackMetric(telemetry);
```

I am seeing the metrics on the Azure portal which is good.  Azure is supposed to support Dimensions and Namespaces.  How can I set this using the TelemetryClient API in Java?

Also, is there anyway to check a return code?  The "trackMetric()" method is void and does not throw any checked exceptions?

Comment: Regarding TelemetryClient API, could you please share some links or sample? is it app insights REST API?

Comment: I am using the Java SDK.  Here is a link on using Java with Application Insights: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-java-get-started#send-your-own-telemetry                                                Here is another link describing the API:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics

Comment: I know the dimension, but the namespace for a custom metric means what? Maybe I'm not understanding the issue well, could you help clarify it more clearly?

Comment: Ivan you should read the docs I posted.

Answer (score 1):

Although not in Java, I had same issue using Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector in C#.

Basically have to create a custom TelemetryInitializer and add that to the app insights configuration.

**Example of adding initializer via C#:**

```
AppInsightsConfig = TelemetryConfiguration.Active;

AppInsightsConfig.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new AppInsightsCloudIdInitializer());
```

**Example of custom AppInsightsCloudIdInitializer:**

```
public class AppInsightsCloudIdInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    private readonly string CloudRoleName;
    private readonly string CloudRoleInstance;

    public AppInsightsCloudIdInitializer()
    {
        CloudRoleName = "MyRole";
        CloudRoleInstance = "MyInstance";
    }

    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        if (telemetry is MetricTelemetry metric)
        {
            metric.MetricNamespace = CloudRoleName;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleInstance) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleName))
        {
            telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleInstance = CloudRoleInstance;
            telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleName = CloudRoleName;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add properties to MetricTelemetry by using the following method.

```
telemetry.getProperties.putIfAbsent(key, value);
```

trackMetric() is void type and this is by design. If you turn on SDKLogs by adding the following tag  in ApplicationInsights.xml, you would see error message when backend responds with error code. SDK also retries on specific error codes.

In order to see the custom dimensions in metric explorer you need to go to "Usage and Estimated Cost" Section and check the Custom metrics preview section.

[image]

Please note that the above steps to enable custom metrics is only needed for viewing them in metrics explore on azure portal. You can still use Analytics tile to view metrics with custom dimensions and do charting with the help of queries.

Comment: If you are on SpringBoot you could also try out the AzureMonitor Micrometer integration! It can help you automatically collect metrics via Micrometer APIs and send it string to Azure portal in a springboot fashion. Here is the link of the: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/tree/master/implementations/micrometer-registry-azure-monitor The 1.1.0-m-1 version of micrometer has this.

Comment: Thanks for the information Dhaval, but I really need to set Dimensions and the Namespace not just Properties.  Also If I understand you correctly I can get error messages into a log by turning on SDKLogs.  I really want to get the response in my code so I can add some error processing.  I do not understand why a method that sends something to a service would not have a return code of some type, or at least throw an exception.

Comment: By turning on SDKLogs, you will also get error messages too. By default we catch all the SDK exceptions because a monitoring solution killing the production app is least what you would desire.

Comment: I just do not understand why I cannot get the error response in my code and take the action I want to versus the SDKLogs way of having it go do a log.  Maybe I want to email or text it, or create an issue in a ticketing system. ...Or if there is a UI involved I may just want to display an error message on the screen.  Can anyone just confirm that I cannot get an error message back, so I will stop chasing this?

Comment: At this moment Application Insights Java SDK doesn't have the functionality of returning the error code when the endpoint responds with failure apart from using SDKLogs. I understand you use case and it's perfectly valid. If you can open a github issue for this we can keep track of it. However, please mind that API would be hard to change unless a major version update happens. This is by design. Apologies I don't have the answer you wanted to hear.

Comment: Dhaval I really appreciate your help clarifying this.  For now I will document where errors are logged.